# Finding a particular solution of a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have been told to find the distance which an object moves in time t, if it starts from rest and has an acceleration of:
$$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=ge^{-kt}.$$
I have been told to show that for small t, the result is approximately:
$$x=\frac{1}{2}gt^2.$$ 
and for very large t, the speed dx/dt is approximately constant (i.e. terminal speed)

My attempt at the solution:

Given;
$$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=ge^{-kt},$$
hence, we can say:
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\int ge^{-kt}dt,$$
or:
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=-\frac{g}{k}e^{-kt}+C_1.$$
We can say that when $t=0$, $\frac{dx}{dt}=0. $
Hence, to satisfy the equation we can say $C_1=\frac{g}{k}.$
and
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=-\frac{g}{k}e^{-kt}+\frac{g}{k}.$$
we see that for $t \rightarrow \infty$, $-\frac{g}{k}e^{-kt} \rightarrow 0. $ Hence, for large t, it is clear that the terminal velocity, v is as follows:
$$v=\frac{g}{k}.$$
Which is a constant value as expected.
Now, to find the distance in which the object moves:
$$x=\int \frac{dx}{dt}dt,$$
$$x=\int -\frac{g}{k}e^{-kt}+\frac{g}{k} dt.$$
or 
$$x=\frac{g}{k^2}e^{-kt}+\frac{g}{k}t+C_2 .$$
This is where I am unsure of what to do, I havn't been told that $x=0,$ when $t=0.$ 
I literally have no idea what to do from this point, if someone could point me in the right direction that'd be very helpful. Thanks.

[Another Attempt]

Using the advice you have all given me, I have computed the definite integral:
$$x=\frac{g}{k^2}e^{-kt}+\frac{g}{k}t+-\frac{g}{k^2} .$$
The question also asked for me to show that for small t, that we can approximate: $x=\frac{1}{2}gt^2.$

Now I am stuck on how I would prove this.

Comment: is $g$ here assumed to be a constant

Comment: You're very close! The distance the object moves is actually the definite integral of $dx/dt$, from $0$ to $t$. Equivalently, the distance it moves is given by $x(t) - x(0)$, where $x$ is as in the last line of your post.

Comment: You’re supposed to find the distance moved in time $t$, not the absolute position, so the second constant of integration is irrelevant. It will cancel when you subtract *x(0)* from $x(t)$

Comment: Thanks, I have found the definite integral as you suggested, Thanks! However once I have the expression of x, I am unsure how to generalise it for small t and hence prove the given relation ($x=\frac{1}{2}gt^2$)

Comment: @George: Expand the solution $x(t)=\frac{g}{k^2}e^{-kt}+\frac{g}{k}t-\frac{g}{k^2}$ around  $x=0$, you get the desired result.

Comment: Use the Taylor series for $x(t)$ around $x=0$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** For small $t$ we have
$$ e^{-kt} \approx 1 - kt + \frac{k^2t^2}{2} $$
via the Taylor series. You can substitute the RHS into your expression for $x(t)$

Answer (score 1):

I do not have a high enough reputation to drop a comment, so I'm posting as an answer.

You've been asked to find the distance an object travels. The distance, $d$, an object travels for time $a \le t \le b$ is

$$d = \int_{a}^b |x'(t)| dt = \int_{a}^b |v(t)| dt$$

where $x(t)$ is your position function and $v(t)$ is your velocity function. So it turns out, the value of $C_2$ is actually not needed!

You already have that

$$x'(t) = -\frac{g}{k}e^{-kt}+\frac{g}{k}$$

So the distance travelled will be

$$d(t) = \int_{0}^t \left|-\frac{g}{k}e^{-ks}+\frac{g}{k}\right| ds$$

I've changed the integration variable to $s$ that the answer you get is in terms of $t$. I'll leave it from here for you to do.